# Flutter разработка, это серьезно?

Tags: flutter

Ребят, недавно я заинтересовался программированием. Рассматривал разные сферы и наткнулся на flutter разработку. Вроде все понравилось, но как-то в разговоре с одним программистом, меня смутило его мнение, «flutter - это как детский конструктор по сборке приложения, типо тильды только немного кодинга»
Знаю, может это вас рассмешило, но меня напугало.

Ответьте, пожалуйста, flutter - это серьезны путь программирования? Там есть сложный кодинг и размышления в реализации или просто конструктор готовых решений?

Comment: Flutter - это вообще не Тильда. Там есть сложный кодинг. Реализации готовых решений нет. Изобрели еще один велосипед.

Comment: *"..но как-то в разговоре с одним программистом.."* - а теперь поговорите с другим программистом, и вас смутит другое )

Comment: А программист небось на каком-нибудь питоне пишет?) Нулевая безопасность, строгая типизация... И правда, детский сад

Answer (score 3):

**Flutter** — бесплатный и открытый набор средств разработки мобильного пользовательского интерфейса, созданный компанией Google и выпущенный в мае 2017 года. Проще говоря, с помощью Flutter возможно создать собственное мобильное приложение с одним массивом кода. Это означает, что для создания двух приложений (IOS и Android) можно использовать единый язык программирования и одну базу кода.

*Сравнивать язык программирования с конструктором, такое себе удовольствие. Не слушайте чужое мнение, ищите информацию самостоятельно, посмотрите как там приложения разрабатываются, примеры в интернете.*

Answer (score 1):

Если фреймворк хороший и им удобно пользоваться, то это не значит, что это конструктор.

Во-первых:

> **Dart** - тьюринг-полный язык, соответственно на нем можно
> решить **любую вычислительную задачу при условии достаточного количества
> времени/вычислительных мощностей**.

Во-вторых:

> Касательно самого **Flutter**, скоро движок **Skia** заменят на
> **Impeller**, который будет оберткой вокруг **Vulkan**/**Metal**. Соответственно можно будет делать вообще все в визуальном плане на
> **Flutter**, в том числе 3д графику/игры.
>
> Сложнее будет придумать **что невозможно**, чем что возможно, потому что возможности настолько неограничены в плане графики.
> Но и сейчас вы можете сделать **абсолютно все** кроме 3d.

Получается следующее:

> У нас есть тьюринг-полный язык (неограниченные возможности при условии
> неограниченного времени/вычислительных мощностей). И при этом поверх
> этого языка есть еще и фреймворк, который делает это все удобным и
> развивается с неимоверной скоростью.

Вывод:

> **Однозначно отличный путь развития**, особенно если вам интересна разработка визуальной части продукта.

**Flutter** написан хорошо, поэтому вы также познакомитесь с реактивным подходом к управлению состоянием, которое пригодится в любой сфере и очень прокачает вас как программиста.

Comment: Тьюринг-полнота - это не о чем. Brainfuck тоже тьюринг-полный.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat тут вообще не о том разговор, человек спросил, конструктор ли это как Tilda